# Why is this bound in one of these arrow invocations, but not the other?

Tags: javascript, scope, binding, this

I am having trouble understanding exactly why `this` has a value in certain cases and not others. I maintain a library, which, stripped down to the bare minimum to explain my confusion looks like this:

```js
const arrayify = f => {
    console.log('init', f.name, !!this);
    return function (thingOrThings, ...args) {
        console.log('arrayify for ', f.name, !!this);
        return [thingOrThings].map(t => f.call(this, t, ...args));
    };
};
class Utils {}
Object.assign(Utils.prototype, {
    setProperty: arrayify(function setPropertyFunc(layer, prop, value) {
        console.log('setPropertyFunc called', !!this); // outputs true
    }),
    hoverPopup(layers, cb, popupOptions = {}) {
        console.log('hoverPopup init', !!this);
        arrayify(function hoverPopupFunc(layer, cb) {
            console.log('hoverPopupFunc called', !!this); // outputs false
        })(layers, cb);
    },
});
```

(It looks overcomplicated because I'm removing all the actual useful stuff. But basically `arrayify` allows a function to take either a single thing, or an array of things, and runs implicitly on every item of the array in the latter case.)

I call it like this:

```js
const U = new Utils();

U.setProperty('mylayer', 'lineColor', 'red');
U.hoverPopup('mylayer', () => 1);
```

Output:

```
init setPropertyFunc false
arrayify for  setPropertyFunc true
setPropertyFunc called true
hoverPopup init true
init hoverPopupFunc false
arrayify for  hoverPopupFunc false
hoverPopupFunc called false
```

So in the first case, calling `U.setProperty` calls `arrayify`, and `this` (inside `arrayify`) has a value.  Also `this` inside the function returned to `setProperty` has a value.

In the second, `U.hoverPopup` calls `arrayify` with no `this` value, and there is also no `this` value in the returned function.

I'm having trouble understanding what is so different about the second case. It's particularly baffling that `this` is *not* defined in the init for `setPropertyFunc` but *is* defined inside the embedded function, while exactly the opposite is true for `hoverPopupFunc`

I'd really like `this` to be defined in both cases - how can I achieve that in the second case? (In the `hoverPopup` case, there is some initialisation that has to happen, so it's not quite as simple as "do this exactly for every item in the array")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at where and how the returned function is invoked to understand the calling context - the `this`.

In the first case, the `setProperty` method on the prototype is the returned function, and it gets called *as a property of the instance*:

```
    U.setProperty('mylayer', 'lineColor', 'red'); // outputs true
//  ^  calling context: this
```

But in the second case, there's no calling context:

```
arrayify(function (layer, cb) {
    console.log('hoverpopup', !!this); // outputs false
})(layers, cb);
```

It's just a plain function that gets immediately invoked. To simplify a bit:

```
arrayify(someFn)(layers, cb)
```

The function being called - the whole `arrayify(someFn)` section - is not a part of an object, but a standalone variable, so there's no calling context.

> I'd really like this to be defined in both cases - how can I achieve that in the second case?

Use `.call` to call a function with a particular `this`.

```
hoverPopup(layers, cb, popupOptions = {}) {
    // do some other initialisation here
    const fn = function (layer, cb) {
        console.log('hoverpopup', !!this); // outputs false
    };
    arrayify(fn).call(this, layers, cb);
},
```

This'll work because, when inside the main body of `hoverPopup`, `this` is the instance:

```
    U.hoverPopup('mylayer', () => 1);
//  ^ calling context: this
```

so doing `arrayify(fn).call(this, layers, cb);` will pass it on like you want.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes a lot of sense. I had tried using `.call()` but had put it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my own explanation to help understand this better.

After the object is instantiated, `U` basically looks like this:

```
{
    setProperty: function (thingOrThings, ...args) {
        console.log('arrayify for ', f.name, !!this);
        return [thingOrThings].map(t => /* ... */);
    },
    hoverPopup: function(layers, cb, popupOptions = {}) {
        console.log('hoverPopup init', !!this);
        arrayify(function hoverPopupFunc(layer, cb) {
            console.log('hoverPopupFunc called', !!this);
        })(layers, cb);
    }
}
```

So, at this point, `setProperty` is simply a function on the object, and so of course when it is called, it has a value for `this`. The fact this function was created by another function (whether arrow or not) is irrelevant.

`hoverPopup` is also a function on the object, and also has a `this` value. But when it calls `arrayify`, that invocation *does not* have a `this` value, because it does not meet any of [the four rules](https://john-dugan.com/this-in-javascript/)

Trying to bind a value of `this` to `arrayify` doesn't work, because it's an arrow function. But you can bind a value to the function returned by arrayify:

```
    hoverPopup(layers, cb, popupOptions = {}) {
        console.log(`hoverPopup init ${this === U}`);
        arrayify(function hoverPopupFunc(layer, cb) {
            console.log(`hoverPopupFunc called ${this === U}`); // outputs true
        }).call(this, layers, cb);
    },
```